data-skip_prompt_cookie not working in Google Sign In
It's likely I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. I'm trying to use the fancy new Sign In With Google system, and I specifically want to use the HTML api (the Javascript API does not seem to support a server-side login URL unless you also use the "redirect" UX mode, which is a log uglier)
The end state I want is for the login UI button to appear on the main page of my (web) app, unless the user is already signed-in, in which case I can render a profile pic. If I put the HTML code in the page, it indeed launches the Google Sign In flow, but after the server-side login I want to redirect back to the same page. Right now, this creates an infinite loop as the Google Sign In flow starts again.
In order for this to not end up in an infinite loop, the guidance seems to be to use the data-skip_prompt_cookie in the HTML tag for the g_id_onload element. Mine looks something like this:
<div id="g_id_onload"
  data-client_id="[REDACTED]"
  data-context="use"
  data-ux_mode="popup"
  data-login_uri="[REDACTED]"
  data-itp_support="true"
  data-skip_prompt_cookie="login"
  data-cancel_on_tap_outside="false">
</div>

The data-skip_prompt_cookie="login" is where I specify to expect a cookie with the name "login"
My server-side (Node.js/ExpressJS) code sets a cookie with the name "login":
res.cookie('login',someValue, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });

I've confirmed (via dev console in the browser) that this cookie does indeed exist on the client, but the Google Login flow still kicks in, and I end up in an infinite loop.
I am not sure why it's not picking up the cookie (are there other undocumented properties of the cookie I need to set?)
Alternatively, how are folks implementing this Google Sign In on the web? My goal is to have the sign-in button flip to a user profile UI (which I can create/render myself) if the user is "logged in", otherwise revert to the Google Sign In automatic flow.
Anyone either know what I'm doing wrong here, or have an alternate approach?

Please make sure that the cookie is in the same domain as the page where the GIS library is being loaded. The data-skip_prompt_cookie should work as expected.

This is all running from localhost, and does not work.
